# Where could I find a simple sample chain spec for substrate-node-template that is fit for production?

Tags: substrate

Ok now that you've done all tutorials in Substrate and run your dev blockchain.  Where could you find sa sample chain spec and genesis settings so that you can run your substrate-node-template in production provided that you will not change anything in the configuration.

Comment: This question would be better asked at https://substrate.stackexchange.com/